# T-SQL sequential updating with two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, window-functions, recursive-query

I have a table created by:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 
(
    id INT,
    multiplier INT,
    col1 DECIMAL(10,5)
)

INSERT INTO table1 
VALUES (1, 2, 1.53), (2, 3, NULL), (3, 2, NULL),
       (4, 2, NULL), (5, 3, NULL), (6, 1, NULL)
```

Which results in:

```
id  multiplier  col1
-----------------------
1   2           1.53000
2   3           NULL
3   2           NULL
4   2           NULL
5   3           NULL
6   1           NULL
```

I want to add a column `col2` which is defined as `multiplier * col1`, however the next value of `col1` then updates to take the previous calculated value of `col2`.

The resulting table should look like:

```
id  multiplier  col1        col2
---------------------------------------
1       2         1.53000     3.06000
2       3         3.06000     9.18000
3       2         9.18000    18.36000
4       2        18.36000    36.72000
5       3        36.72000   110.16000
6       1       110.16000   110.16000
```

Is this possible using T-SQL? I've tried a few different things such as joining `id` to `id - 1` and have played around with a sequential update using `UPDATE` and setting variables but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive CTE might be the best approach.  Assuming your `id`s have no gaps:

```
with cte as (
      select id, multiplier, convert(float, col1) as col1, convert(float, col1 * multiplier) as col2
      from table1
      where id = 1
      union all
      select t1.id, t1.multiplier, cte.col2 as col1, cte.col2 * t1.multiplier
      from cte join
           table1 t1
           on t1.id = cte.id + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=58bd83cee3711ff93d73b0d3a952d565) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that I converted the destination type to `float`, which is convenient for this sort of operation.  You can convert back to `decimal` if you prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this would require an aggregate/window function that computes the product of column values. Such set function does not exists in SQL though. We can work around this with arithmetics:

```
select
    id,
    multiplier,
    coalesce(min(col1) over() * exp(sum(log(multiplier)) over(order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)), col1) col1,
    min(col1) over() * exp(sum(log(multiplier)) over(order by id)) col2
from table1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2b6590cfadf42055541e140b7c63f1a3)**:

```
id | multiplier |   col1 |   col2
-: | ---------: | -----: | -----:
 1 |          2 |   1.53 |   3.06
 2 |          3 |   3.06 |   9.18
 3 |          2 |   9.18 |  18.36
 4 |          2 |  18.36 |  36.72
 5 |          3 |  36.72 | 110.16
 6 |          1 | 110.16 | 110.16
```

This will fail if there are negative `multiplier`s.

If you wanted an `update` statement:

```
with cte as (
    select col1, col2,
        coalesce(min(col1) over() * exp(sum(log(multiplier)) over(order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)), col1) col1_new,
        min(col1) over() * exp(sum(log(multiplier)) over(order by id)) col2_new
    from table1
)
update cte set col1 = col1_new, col2 = col2_new
```